# How do you think I can solve Error C2664?

Tags: c++, c2664

I have little problem.
I am getting the error mentioned in the title while compiling.
The line where the error appears is pItemData->GetName(), line.

But even if I change the order, whatever is on that line gives the same error about it.

When I remove the #ifdef tags, their problems go away. But when I add these, this problem arises.

```
'void CPythonTextTail::RegisterItemTextTail(DWORD,const char *,CGraphicObjectInstance *,char *)' : 3 arguments cannot be converted from 'const char *' to 'CGraphicObjectInstance *'.
```

Related files and definitions(.h file):

```
#ifdef ENABLE_WEAPON_EVOLUTION_SYSTEM
void CPythonTextTail::RegisterItemTextTail(DWORD VirtualID, const char* c_szText, 
CGraphicObjectInstance* pOwner, char * evolutionMergeText)
#else
void CPythonTextTail::RegisterItemTextTail(DWORD VirtualID, const char* c_szText, 
CGraphicObjectInstance* pOwner)
#endif
```

Error line(.cpp file)

```
#ifdef ENABLE_WEAPON_EVOLUTION_SYSTEM
char evolutionMergeText[100]; char evolutionText[6][10] = { "", "Yaygın ", "Seyrek ", "Nadir 
", "Efsane ", "Eşsiz " };
sprintf(evolutionMergeText, "%s%s", evolutionText[evolution], pItemData->GetName());
#endif
rkTextTail.RegisterItemTextTail(
    dwVirtualID,
#ifdef ENABLE_WEAPON_EVOLUTION_SYSTEM
    evolutionMergeText,
#endif
    pItemData->GetName(),
    &pGroundItemInstance->ThingInstance

 );
```

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message?  The function expects a `CGraphicObjectInstance *` and you're passing a `const char *`.  Which argument did you think was a `CGraphicObjectInstance *`?

Comment: char* evolutionMergeText when i add this i get this error. The const char already existed and works fine. However, after adding the char* evolutionMergeText that I'm trying to include, it gives such an error for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the parameters is wrong. `evolutionMergeText` argument is the last in the function. Change the order

```
rkTextTail.RegisterItemTextTail(
    dwVirtualID,
    pItemData->GetName(),
    &pGroundItemInstance->ThingInstance
#ifdef ENABLE_WEAPON_EVOLUTION_SYSTEM
    , evolutionMergeText
#endif
 );
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried that. The compilation process was completed without any problems. However, when I enter the game from the compiled .exe file, I see that the code is ineffective. In addition; The order in the files where I got the codes is the same. I added it in the same way by looking, it compiles without any problems, but it gives me this error. The order in the files I got the codes is the same as I showed.

Comment: Never copy other code to your code if you do not understand what other code does.

Comment: These codes are the codes of a plugin for the game. All other parts of the plugin are working fine, but finally, I couldn't fix this shortcoming.